# Diffusion Models - Loss normalization for different noise schedules

Tags: generative-model, diffusion-models

With reference to the paper "[Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239)", and running the code given in [this notebook](https://github.com/acids-ircam/diffusion_models/blob/main/diffusion_02_model.ipynb) showing a simple example on "flattened" data, I have the following issue --- **the normalization of the loss is strongly dependent on the choice of the noise schedule**.

That is, by changing the noise schedule (while keeping all the rest of the model intact) it may happen to obtain a lower loss although, in practice, the target distribution is modelled more poorly (visually obvious, but a simple KL calculation confirms it).

I can't wrap my head around this.  The loss used in the notebook is the "simple loss" from the paper (their Equation 14):

$$L_{simple}(\theta) := E_{t,x_0,\epsilon}\big[|| \pmb{\epsilon} - \pmb{\epsilon}_\theta (\sqrt{\bar{\alpha_t}}\pmb{x}_0 + \sqrt{1-\bar{\alpha}_t}\pmb{\epsilon}, t))||^2 \big]$$

from which I deduce $\pmb{\epsilon} - \pmb{\epsilon}_\theta$ should always converge to the same range because $\pmb{\epsilon} \sim N(0,\pmb{I})$, but in practice it is not like that.

In turn, the problem becomes that when I run models with different schedules, I cannot compare the results based on the loss, that is, I cannot automate the choice of the best model/schedule combination.

Assuming I didn't make any silly mistake, my question is twofold:

1 - How can I mathematically, intuitively see where the different schedule choice affects the loss?

2- How can I "normalize" the loss, so that it becomes comparable across different schedules and models?

---

PS: I also tried to replace the "simple loss" with the full loss of Equation 12 (where I assumed that the additional terms would have taken care of the normalization related to the noise schedule):

$$L(\theta) := E_{t,x_0,\epsilon}\big[|| { \beta_t^2 \over 2\sigma_t^2 \alpha_t } \pmb{\epsilon} - \pmb{\epsilon}_\theta (\sqrt{\bar{\alpha_t}}\pmb{x}_0 + \sqrt{1-\bar{\alpha}_t (1 - \bar{\alpha_t})}\pmb{\epsilon}, t))||^2 \big]$$

... but the resulting loss across the epochs is too noisy to understand whether it really sets the same dynamic range independently of the noise schedule.